# Plain text search in markdown text

Tags: c#, search, markdown

I am trying to write code (in C#) that can search for any plain-text word or phrase in a markdown file.  Currently I'm doing this by a long-winded method: convert the markdown to HTML, strip HTML element tags out of the HTML text and then use a simple regular expression to search that for the word/phrase in question.  Needless to say, this can be pretty slow.

A concrete example might show the problem.  Say the markdown file contains

`Something ***significant***`

I would like to be able to find that by providing the search phrase `something significant` (i.e. ignoring the `***`'s).

Is there an efficient way of doing this (i.e. that avoids the conversion to HTML) and doesn't involve me writing my own markdown parser?

**Edit:**
I want a generic way to search for any text or phrase in markdown text that contains any valid markdown formatting.  The first answers were ways to match the specific text example I gave.

**Edit:**
I should have made it clear: this is required for a simple user-facing search and the markdown files could contain any valid markdown formatting.  For this reason I need to be able to ignore anything in the markdown that the user wouldn't see as text if they converted the markdown to HTML.  E.g. the markdown text that specifies an image (like `![Valid XHTML](http://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10).` should be skipped during the search).  Converting to HTML produces decent results for the user because it then reasonably accurately reflects what a user sees (but it's just a slow solution, esp when there's a lot of markdown text to look through).

Comment: I might be wrong, but the impression I got from your question is that that is one of a number of possible examples. Given that all the answers you're receiving seem to special case that one, it might help to give a couple more.

Comment: Showing your current code will help greatly, for example to answer: should the words be in the searched order? Can there be other words between the words, and what kinds of whitespace is allowed? Won't a simple repeated `IndexOf()` work too? Are you sure you want to re-invent the search engine?

Comment: @MatthewHaugen you're quite right; I've edited the question to emphasize that.

Comment: @CodeCaster I definitively *don't* want to re-invent a search engine!  To answer your other questions, I don't mind what the pattern-matching technique is (`IndexOf`, `Regex`, whatever) and I only want to match multiple words in order with nothing between them (isn't that implied by saying I want to match a *phrase*)?

Comment: Sure that's implied, but I'd rather have it specified explicitly to make sure you mean with it what it actually means, not everyone here holds true to the terminology they use. I think @dariogriffo's answer is fine. You just have to split the search phrase on whitespace and build your regex from there. Again, if you show your current code, you'll get more specific answers.

Comment: I feel the desire to point out that at some level you will have to use or implement a Markdown parser to do what you want. It would be possible to use regex, but I feel you would end up basically writing a parser in regex which would be verbose and probably not clean. I would first pass through the Markdown and strip out any markdown tokens effectively converting the text to raw text. Then you just need to search the raw text. If needed, you can save the raw text beside the markdown text for easier searching later (don't have to re-parse every time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regexp

```
var str = "Something ***significant***";
var regexp = new Regex("Something.+significant.+");
Console.WriteLine(regexp.Match(str).Success);
```

Comment: This would only solve that one very specific *example*.

Comment: I dont have all the list of things you want to match, I based on your example, just replace it within a foreach(var whatever_you_want_to_match in whatevetever_collection_you_want_to_use){ var new Regex(whatever_you_want_to_match);

Comment: Yeah, I may have to do this.  I was hoping to not have to write many (or a single very complex) Regex pattern to strip out all the sorts of  markdown text that a user wouldn't 'see' if they were viewing it converted to HTML,

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same thing. I think of one way to achieve that.

Your method has two steps.

1. Get the plain text out of the markdown source (which has also two steps. Markdown->HTML and HTML->stripped to plain text)
2. Search within the plain text

Now, if the markdown source is persisted in a data store, then you may be able to also persist the plain text for search purposes only. So the step to extract the plain text from the markdown may be executed only once when persisting the markdown source (or every time the markdown source is updated), but the code that actually searches in the markdown could be executed immediately on the already persisted plain text data as many times as you want.

For example, if you have a relational DB with a column like `markdown_text`, you could also create a `plain_text` column and recreate its value every time the `markdown_text` column is changed.

Users won't bother if saving their markdown takes a few milliseconds (or even seconds) more than before. Users tend to feel safe when something that alters the system's state takes some time (they feel that something is actually happening in the system), rather than happen immediately (they feel that something went wrong and their command did not execute). But they will feel frustrated if searching took more than a few ms to complete. In general users want queries to complete immediately but commands to take some time (not more than a few seconds though).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string input = "Something ***significant***";
string v = input.Replace("***", "");
Console.WriteLine(v)
```

look this example: [enter link description here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace)

Comment: Markdown is a markup language that supports many more markup notations than just `***`. Replacing the one isn't going to help.